# what is the judgment for those who perfom shirk

Tags: fiqh, sin, knowing-islam

Asalam aleykum Warahmatul Laahi wabarakatuh,
Peace be upon our prophet Muhammad S.A.W.

I have no knowledge about islam but I wish to learn and understand it In Shaa ALLAH. Someone ask me for the people that worship other things beside ALLAH(S.W), In a afterlife would they be worship the thing that they worship in duniya?. And if the fire is promised to them would they be worship the thing that they worship in Hell fire?.
Or they wouldn't worship none they would just receive what they deserve or judgments. How can I answer him/her, I apologies for my English am using translator.

Comment: Worship isn't a topic in the hereafter except with du'a. And the people of shirk shall expect a punishment.

Comment: @Medi1Saif what kind of punishment is there any instruction or specifications for the punishment?